# what does this.state references to in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just started working in react since couple of days and I am confused with following

1. If each react component have state isolated to the scope of that component or is there only one state for complete app ?
2. How does react differentiates between a Component function and a normal function? Is it the return value?

   const component = () => (
     //jsx DOM element
   );

   const obj = () => 'return value';

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If each react component have state isolated to the scope of that component or is there only one state for complete app ?

It's an instance property of the individual component, which is why you access it via `this.state`. It is not global to the app.

> How does react differentiates between a Component function and a normal function? Is it the return value?

It doesn't. If you take a function that was never meant to be used as a component, and then use it as a component, react will do as you ask, but the results will probably not be useful.

For example, if you create a function that looks like this:

```
const Sum = (a, b) => a + b;
```

And then try to render the following:

```
<div>
  <Sum />
</div>
```

React will not throw any errors or anything, but you'll see [object Object][object Object] on the page